# Shopify verification failed

Tags: javascript, shopify, hmac, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am trying to create a public app in Shopify. I can set the scopes required our app. During installation it asks for shopify verification. I have referred this document https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth#verification. I have passed message as code=%code-from-shopify%&shop=%shop.myshopify.com%&state=%state-from-shopify%&timestamp=%timestamp-from-shopify% with secret as Shopify app's secret key but it never match with hmac present in url as a parameter.

I have created an app 3 years ago, it is working fine as I mentioned above but when I created an app 9 days ago is not working and the secret key for this new app is starting as shpss_

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you add more details e.g. the steps, request URLs, Shopify responses, screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

- First thing please check your SHOPIFY_KEY and SHOPIFY_SECRET is this correct and are you using the same in your code.
- Once you redirect from shopify to your given call backUrl you will get hmac and code from request.

Here is the code to get Access Token from hmac

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== "hmac" && $key != "signature") {
        $hashArray[] = $key . "=" . $value;
    }
}
$hashString   = implode($hashArray, "&");
$hashedString = hash_hmac("sha256", $hashString, 'YOUR_SHOPIFY_SECRET');

/* compare resulting hashed string with hmac parameter */
if ($_REQUEST['hmac'] !== $hashedString) {
    return 403;
}

$shopUrl  = "https://" . $_REQUEST["shop"] . "/admin/oauth/access_token.json";
$postData = http_build_query(
    array(
        "client_id"     => 'YOUR_SHOPIFY_KEY',
        "client_secret" => 'YOUR_SHOPIFY_SECRET',
        "code"          => $_REQUEST["code"],
    )
);

/* Call using curl post you will get Access token in JSON */
$result = shop_auth_curl_request_call($shopUrl, $postData);

$tokenResponse = json_decode($result, true);

$tokenResponse['access_token'] // In JSON you will get access token
```